# Need to iterate the result and then execute immediate each result using pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql, execute-immediate

So I have this query:

```
select 'alter index '||a.index_owner||'.'||a.index_name|| ' rebuild partition '||a.partition_name 
from dba_ind_partitions a
where a.index_name in ('IDX_PI_T_BSCS_CONTRACT_HISTOR2', 'IDX_PI_T_BSCS_CONTRACT_HISTOR3',  'IDX_PI_T_BSCS_RATEPLAN_HIST_C1')
and a.status =  'UNUSABLE'
```

And I need to iterate over the result and then `execute immediate` each statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you'd convert `SELECT` you wrote into a cursor FOR loop and *execute* it.

Here's how; I can't test it, but - if `SELECT` returns what you want, that's the way to do it.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> BEGIN
  2     FOR cur_r
  3        IN (SELECT    'alter index '
  4                   || a.index_owner
  5                   || '.'
  6                   || a.index_name
  7                   || ' rebuild partition '
  8                   || a.partition_name
  9                      as l_alter
 10              FROM dba_ind_partitions a
 11             WHERE     a.index_name IN ('IDX_PI_T_BSCS_CONTRACT_HISTOR2',
 12                                        'IDX_PI_T_BSCS_CONTRACT_HISTOR3',
 13                                        'IDX_PI_T_BSCS_RATEPLAN_HIST_C1')
 14                   AND a.status = 'UNUSABLE')
 15     LOOP
 16        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cur_r.l_alter;
 17     END LOOP;
 18  END;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I see, tried it out and says I need to declare l_alter identifier:
ORA-06550: line 16, column 25:
PLS-00201: identifier 'L_ALTER' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 16, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Ah, sorry ... should have been `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cur_r.l_alter;`

Comment: Hm, I don´t know if its because of SQL version, but sql delevoper dosnt recognize it, I had to write it like so: "cur_r in l_alter". And even after that it still says there is something wrong with the loop clause, here is the error, it´s easier:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 13:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:

   in
ORA-06550: line 15, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , and or

Comment: Shouldn't be. I connected to my database and ran that code; works OK. Of course, regarding the fact that I don't have your indexes, but - there's no **error** in that code.

Comment: Ok, will have to dig more on this side then, but thank you very much for the help!! It was very appreciated!!